# User Information List Add item programmatically

Tags: infopath, caml-query

I'm using a CAML batch file to add items to a list using SharePoint List Web Service on my InfoPath form.

The batch file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Batch>
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
    <Field Name="Employee" >Jimbo Alba</Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

It also works for "Person or Group" field types.

```
   <Field Name="Person" >1</Field>
```

That is if you know that the person's ID in the User Information List is 1. In case the person is not yet in the User Information List how can I add it using InfoPath or through code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add user to a SharePoint portal using [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) method.
This way he will be also added to the User Information List.

The example of usage:

```
SPList userInformationList = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList; 
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(@"DOMAIN\username"); 
SPListItem userItem = userInformationList.Items.GetItemById(user.ID);
// do whatever you need with userItem or with user.ID
```

Comment: Very promising answer from you @omlin. I'll post back after I try it.

Comment: you're welcome! and dare to mention, that here at SharePoint StackExchange, people thank through upvoting and accepting the question as the right solution :)

Comment: @omlin - Do you know if this is possible with SharePoint ADO.NET Data Services? I have been struggling to figure out how to do something similar from a client machine (not running on the server).

Comment: @Pandincus - you'd better use SharePoint Client Object Model. It has almost same objects, for example, Web object has SiteUserInfoList property, and so on... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.siteuserinfolist.aspx If this information will not help, I recommend you to create a new separated question.